# Report Rest API (asynchronous run and excel export)

Tags: data-export, asynchronous, reports-api, excel

I'm trying to use Report Rest API to filter and export some of my reports. My first approach with synchronous report runs works pretty well, but I bumped into 500 batches' run per hour limitation. I want to refactor my code to make asynchronous runs, but I can't find out how to export at this approach. 
After I get my report instance after run as link `/services/data/v47.0/analytics/reports/[report id]/instances/[report instance id]`, I try to download report as [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_download_excel.htm) says but when I change the request header to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` I get error message saying:

> [ {
>     "errorCode" : "UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE",
>     "message" : "The Analytics API only supports JSON content type in both request and response bodies. Specify requests with content type as application/​json."
>   } ]

Anyone trying something like that? Is it even possible to get report results after the asynchronous report run?